# Can't deploy debug version of my app after upgrading to iOS 4.2

Tags: xcode, ios, debug-symbols, ios-4.2

I just upgraded to XCode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2, and I upgraded my device to 4.2.1.  Now I can only deploy a release version of my app.  How do I deploy a debug version of my app?  Do I need to install debug symbols on the device?  If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this can solve your problem, at least it worked for me:

1. Change the build settings for base
   sdk to latest iOS version
2. Change the active configuration to
   Release
3. Choose Device in the same menu as
   configuration
4. Switch back to Debug configuration
5. Choose Device in the same menu again

/Jakob

Comment: I followed this sequence, and it did not work.  Then I did some other similar seemingly random sequence of steps using either the Project menu, or the dropdown menu in the toolbar, or the Target Info aka Project Info, aka Project Settings dialog. I was finally able to deploy a debug version of my app on the device, but I don't know how.  So, thanks, I guess.  Joys of learning a new dev environment.

Comment: Ok, good to hear that you got it working at last, anyway. In the release notes to the iOS 4.2 it says that a simple restart of xcode should fix the problem but I don't think it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the developer.apple.com site, sign in to the iOS member site, on the home tab is the Launch Assistant that will help you install your app to your device.

Comment: This did not solve the problem.  I can deploy a release version of my app on the device OK. The problem is I cannot deploy a debug version of my app.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods for running (Release vs. Debug Modes):

A) Run in Profiling Mode (it has Release Build set by default. Note: the NDEBUG macro is NOT set!)

B) Change the Run [appname] part of your build Scheme to Release mode temporarily, then back to the Debug default afterwards.

As for the device deployment part, I have not encountered this problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you use an old iPod device, you should support armv6 version.

set "Architectures" , add "armv6" in both Debug and Release mode.